How to send a solana/web3.js transaction to a anchor program?
I want to send a transaction to a anchor program,
I have found the function discriminator
const dis = [125,112,23,1,23,45,24,12]

I have checked ,that this is the right function, Now i want pass a vec<64> followed by vec<Pubkey>, In anchor i can do this but i can only send 24 of those in array, So i want to do a regular tx,
Can anyone tell me how can i do that?
